# X Server unable to start under Linux 4.5 in Arch virtual box guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, xorg, arch-linux

I recently ran `paceman -Syu` to upgrade my system as usual but after installing the newest Linux kernel, the X Server could no longer start and produced this error in the log file

`AddScreen/ScreenInit failed for driver 0`

I'm running this Arch system under virtual box. I tried installing the `xf86-video-intel` driver, but that didn't solve the problem either.

Right now I downgraded the kernel and headers back to Linux 4.4 but I would like to resolve this problem the right way instead of using an old kernel.

Edit: This issue seemed to have resolved itself as it appears to have been caused by an upstream conflict with the guest additions package. As of now, the new package worked fine with the 4.5 kernel.

Comment: VirtualBox like VmWare use their own drivers for the **virtual** video hardware. `xf86-video-intel` wouldn't have worked. Check the Arch Wiki for what you need to do to get video working.

Comment: I think those virtual box repos should update with the system, though the new kernel seems to break the driver.

Comment: I have had exactly the same problem, and I have not been able to fix  it, I believe something is broken upstream.  I have noticed that packages like `virtualbox-guest-utils` have been flagged as `out of date`, see for instance here,  https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/virtualbox-guest-utils/.I guess we can only wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

I just setup ArchLinux using Windows 7 x64 as the host and initially used the Vbox packages provided by Arch. Got X going but no desktop resize. So to fix it I,

- Removed packages `pacman -Rs virtualbox-guest-utils`
- Shutdown guest
- Upgraded VirtualBox Windows app to latest ( 5.0.18 r106667 )
- Upgraded VirtualBox extension pack
- Booted guest
- From the VirtualBox menu Devices clicked on `Insert Guest Additions CD Image"
- Mounted CD image using `mount /dev/cdrom /mnt`
- Run the script `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` which **compiled** and **installed** the matching tools and drivers for the version of VirtualBox I am running.
- Rebooted

I checked that the kernel modules have loaded `lsmod | grep -i vbox`. Should look like this,

```
# lsmod | grep -i vbox
vboxvideo              45056  2
ttm                    73728  1 vboxvideo
drm_kms_helper        106496  1 vboxvideo
drm                   245760  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,vboxvideo
syscopyarea            16384  2 drm_kms_helper,vboxvideo
sysfillrect            16384  2 drm_kms_helper,vboxvideo
sysimgblt              16384  2 drm_kms_helper,vboxvideo
vboxsf                 40960  0
vboxguest             196608  6 vboxsf,vboxvideo
```

At this stage I couldn't get Xorg to start either. In this [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192782) it was mentioned that the old /etc/X11/xorg.conf file should be deleted. Tried it and voila!

Now startx command works and the screen also resizes! Only issue is that when the guest is in windowed mode the text selection in Konsole using the mouse is off by one line. Works fine in fullscreen mode. Oh well... :)